# Seeking Help to Improve Execution Speed of Code for Hiding Sections on Paginated WordPress Pages

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, pagination

I'm working on a WordPress site and encountering pagination issues. I want to prevent certain sections of the homepage from displaying when a user clicks on the next page. To achieve this, I've implemented the following code in my child theme's functions.php file. It works, but there's a noticeable 6-second delay before the code takes effect. During this time, the section I'm trying to hide remains visible for several moments before disappearing.

```
function hide_elements_on_paginated_pages() {
    // Check if it's a paginated page (not the homepage)
    if (is_paged()) {
        // Add JavaScript to hide the elements and log a message
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {';
        echo '    console.log("Hiding elements on paginated page.");'; // Log this message
        echo '    var elementsToHide = document.querySelectorAll(".elementor-column-gap-default > .elementor-column > .elementor-element-populated");';
        echo '    for (var i = 0; i < elementsToHide.length; i++) {';
        echo '        elementsToHide[i].style.display = "none";';
        echo '    }';
        echo '});';
        echo '</script>';
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'hide_elements_on_paginated_pages', 999); // Using 'wp_head' to add it to the <head>
```

I'm seeking a solution to expedite the execution of this code so that the specified section is hidden immediately upon page load, without the noticeable delay. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: CSS : `.elementor-column-gap-default > .elementor-column > .elementor-element-populated { display: none }`

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. My goal is to display a specific section on my homepage, but when I navigate to the next page using pagination, I want that section to disappear. I attempted a solution like the following:

```css
body:not(.home) .elementor-column-gap-default > .elementor-column > .elementor-element-populated { 
    display: none;
}
```

However, this approach didn't yield the desired result.

Comment: `body:not(.home)` I take it only the "home" page has `body` with class `home`

Comment: _"However, this approach didn't yield the desired result."_ - we can't tell if that's because the selector is not a match, or perhaps simply because this gets _overwritten_ by a more specific rule. // body also gets the class `paged` added for every pagination page except the first one, maybe that would make for a more appropriate criterion.

Comment: @CBroe, the selector is indeed a match. I tested it under the developer tools I believe there's a possibility that it's being overridden by another specific rule.

I also tried using `paged`, like this: `[class*="paged"] #topsection {display: none;}`. In this case, I went into Elementor and assigned the sections I wanted to hide the ID of "topsection," then applied the custom CSS. This worked but only on Desktop. 
As of now, the JavaScript function is the only solution that works for both, however I need to fix the issue with the delay

Comment: _"I believe there's a possibility that it's being overridden by another specific rule"_ - this is coding, not religion - so you don't have to "believe", you can _go check_. Your browser dev tools will tell you what styles actually apply and where from, so go and check. And go and emulate a mobile device, and check again. Likely there are simply different rules applying for desktop and mobile.

Comment: @CBroe, I believed it was already implied in my message since I tested it using developer tools, and it worked. However, when I apply it via custom CSS in WordPress, it doesn't have the same effect. Nevertheless, the script function works perfectly; I just need it to execute more quickly. Do you have any suggestions on how to make it execute faster so that the hidden section is concealed immediately upon page load?

Comment: _"However, when I apply it via custom CSS in WordPress, it doesn't have the same effect."_ -see, and here at this point I would have considered it to be _implied_, that you go check again then, in the _real_ context that this gets used in ... _"I just need it to execute more quickly"_ - if you append it to the footer instead of the head, then you won't need to bind this to the `DOMContentLoaded` event, you can just execute the code directly then. [...]

Comment: [...] Although that might not change too much, since DOMContentLoaded already fires pretty early. If it was still too slow then, you'd have to place the script element _immediately_ after the elements in question - but that would probably be a hard position to "find" to begin with, I doubt you'd achieve that any other way than by hacking this into the relevant template file then. And then you could rather make it not generate those elements in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe I appreciate the feedback. I originally appended the code to the footer and it was still slow to executer.

Comment: There's another detail I neglected to mention: the CSS `[class*="paged"] #topsection {display: none;}` works as expected when I use developer tools to emulate a mobile device, but it doesn't have the same effect when accessed on an actual phone.

Comment: You mentioned that already; but I can't tell you _why_ it behaves differently between emulating a device, and using a real one. Maybe your site does some additional user agent sniffing or other stuff to try and "identify" a mobile device, that dev tools can't really emulate ... don't know, too many details lacking here. Either hook up an actual device via USB for remote debugging, or use a service like BrowserStack maybe, to investigate what exactly the problem is with that.

Comment: @CBroe, appreciate all the feedback. I will look into BrowserStack to see if I can get some more insights. Thanks!

Comment: I just realized it isn't that the script is slow to execute, but rather, it does not execute until I touch the screen. I tried tweaking the javascript function  so that the code will execute as soon as the entire page and its resources are ready by adding a load eventlister.  It did not work. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I was able to get this to work with the JavaScript code in the opening. The reason there was a delay in the code's execution was that the option "Delay JavaScript Execution" was checked in WP Rocket. Unchecking this allowed the code to work as intended. I appreciate everyone who tried to help. Thanks!